# The "Hot" tab algorithm changed recently, does not appear to be working as intended

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, hot-questions

**Someone add `status completed` on this question and then reject this edit**

Recently I have seen a lot of older high view count questions on the [Hot tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot). Was the [algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected/4789#4789) recently changed?

Before I used to see questions that had a lot of activity (many updates to Q's or A's) but may not have had a high view count. Now the list just seems to be dominated by the "super questions" with > 100k views that just happened to have a update within the last few days.

I don't like the new formula. It has turned the "Hot" tab into something like the "Week" or "Month" tab. As of right now there are only 4 questions on the "Hot" tab that has less than 10k views and the smallest one of those has 4k. What I expect to see is questions similar to what I would see in the Stack Exchange "Hot Questions" drop-down but filtered to only the site you are on, not the questions with the most views that happen to have updated recently.

This algorithm change seems to have affected all Stack Exchange sites, [Super User is worse than Stack Overflow](https://superuser.com/?tab=hot), In the top 5 "Hot" questions the most recently modified one was done 8 days ago and the number 1 slot has not been modified in the past 25 days.

Comment: Woah... Yeah. Something definitely changed...

Comment: I'm going to retag this as a bug since I highly doubt that this is the intended behavior.

Comment: I looked at the top 10 hot questions, and all of them have been edited or answered in the past 24 hours.  That makes it look like activity is getting them on the hot list, and high views/votes are keeping them there.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Soo, does that mean something is wrong and being corrected, or is by-design and there is no intention of changing it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It looks wrong to me. A dev will have to respond for us to know if it's by design or not.

Comment: Kind of surprised got no official response yet. Could it be because this was originally tagged `discussion` then re-taged `bug` it never got put on some "to take a look at" list

Comment: Nope, [looks like I just need to be patient](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177776/do-questions-that-get-re-tagged-as-bug-miss-out-on-some-queue).

Comment: @Scott we aren't ignoring you - I am on the case - however, this is a bit of an odd week, as it is the "get the team together in one place" kind of week

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turns out that I suck. A `true` incorrectly became a `false` when I was moving some code around. I would blame it on the boolean, but it was totally me. Building out in a few minutes.

Sorry about that, and my apologies.

Comment: (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻) Your killin us smalls. Hot questions is srs-business. Thanks for getting that fixed! +1.

Comment: Just out of curioustiy, what was boolean where you checking that you had backwards?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain as you observed, there is a lot of commonality between the functionality of "hot" / "month" / "week". The boolean here influenced how time influences the query.