# Do questions that get re-tagged as bug miss out on some queue?

Tags: support, meta, specific-question

I asked my question [The "Hot" tab algorithm changed recently, does not appear to be working as intended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177205/the-hot-tab-algorithm-changed-recently-does-not-appear-to-be-working-as-inten?noredirect=1#comment533126_177205) a week ago and got a LOT of interest (32 up-votes, 4 favorites, and 223 views).

I originally had the question tagged as [a discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/177205/1), however [Mystical re-tagged my question as bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/177205/2) (which I think was a good idea) but I have had absolutely no response from any kind of devs on it.

Because my question was originally tagged as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) then changed to [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) did it never get added from some queue for devs to look at, or am I just impatient and need to calm down and wait for an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, they're slightly less eligible for answers that aren't really answers but just discuss whatever topic was raised in the question.

They also languish in a dedicated queue that's checked regularly by developers who rage and fume over the ever-increasing volume and occasionally take steps to reduce it by fixing things.

Worst-case: your bug might be further retagged with a status tag.

Comment: Calm down and sit on my hands, got it :) (will accept in 3 min)