# Has SO ever found a new better solution to a problem

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, example-questions

So I was looking at [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733457/given-a-sorted-array-can-we-build-a-sorted-array-of-the-sums-of-all-pairs-in-o?noredirect=1#comment25852272_17733457) in which someone asked for a solution that hasn't been figured out or doesn't exist at all. This made me wonder if stackoverflow ever produced a solution to a problem that was better than the current solutions to the problem at the time. If anyone has an example of this that would be really interesting.

**Keep in mind I'm sure people find solutions to little problems on SO all the time but I'm looking for something a little more significant**

Comment: for whoever downvoted don't tell me you wouldn't be curious as to if this has happened

Comment: To be honest, I am interested.  Equally though we do hate fun round here

Comment: @RichardTingle lol i figured if someone is allowed to ask who are the famous developers on SO and get 100+ UV's than I can at least ask a question that is interesting to developers on a deeper level

Comment: Define significant....

Comment: For one, how significant is significant? That's rather subjective, don't you think? And secondly, if someone makes such a discovery - they need to prove it is "new and better" and let people know.

Comment: @Oded I'm mean to figure out if it's significant the best way is to post it and let people looking at this question decide, I would appreciate any examples

Comment: I don't think we need to debate the precise definition of "significant" in this case. This is an interesting question. Can we (on SO and other sites) produce better mousetraps for some value of "better"?

Comment: I assume aaroman means (for a random example) were any of the list sorting algorithms originally devised to the question "How do I sort this list". Or similar now mainstream techniques

Comment: @AnnaLear how is this not a trap for "Well there is this one" "Nah, that's not really significant enough"?

Comment: I don't know what the commotion is about, WCS someone posts an answer and it is not deemed significant, the world won't explode

Comment: @Bart Who cares? This is meta. ;) I don't see a reason to shut down the discussion when it's pretty clear (to me, at least) what the *intent* is even if the wording isn't 100% precise.

Comment: @Bart I think your, wrongly, assuming I'm just gonna shutdown any answer and say it's not good enough. That being said if people actually get into this I would wait a decent time to accept an answer

Comment: Meh, have at it. As long as you don't have fun....

Comment: @Bart I'll try my best :)

Comment: Not SO, but another Stack Exchange site: [Original proofs generated on the parent site](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/784/original-proofs-generated-on-the-parent-site)

Comment: @Gilles thank you very cool, that's basically my question on a different site, unfortunately for me I think I lost my proof writing prowess

Comment: This question gives me a headache

Comment: @Yve sorry, but you can't tell me you aren't curious at all

Comment: I think one good answer and this question will turn around and you might get your 100 upvotes. A couple more downvoted though and it'll be off the front page and banished forever

Comment: The problem with this question still lies in the nature of Stack Overflow though. Academia are not the holy grail, but on an academic level site (of which there are a couple in the network) I would expect there to be results which provably lead to an advancement of the state-of-the-art, providing a clear and perhaps even publishable "better". Stack Overflow is not such a site however. And while I can't exclude such content from having been contributed, I'm not sure there is a satisfying answer to this question.

Comment: @aaronman I've had 3 hours sleep, haven't had a coffee yet, look at that and go erggg... there are so many innovations in programming and although SO is a good site, it's not the place where this happens, for many reasons, it's a site for programming enthusiasts and, not an open source project, or developer site..  seriously, this is the last comment I want to make on it, this question really does NOT interest me

Comment: @RichardTingle there are plenty of downvoted questions with upvoted answers, one is not, necessarily, dependent upon the other

Comment: @Yve not to be a jerk, but then you shouldn't have commented or voted on it

Comment: @aaronman I have the same right as any community member to read and vote on a question I do not think is a good question for this site. I am allowed to have my opinion, and I am allowed to disagree with you. If I say- You "shouldn't" have posted the question.. how does that sound? hm like I'm an ass

Comment: @Yve when you say "this question really does NOT interest me" that implies what I said before not that u dont think the question is a good fit

Comment: People! Yve has downvoted as shes entitled to, shes also explained why which is an added courtesy. Im not sure a discussion as to who is entitled to vote for which reasons is constructive

Comment: who the heck argues with a kangaroo anyway.. omg O.O

Comment: @Yve Well I'm safe from all arguing, because anyone who argues with a Doorknob is definitely very... Odd :P

Comment: Stack Overflow solved a problem of low signal/noise ratio at forums.

Comment: @Doorknob, I disagree. No one is safe here, not even Doorknobs, Unicorns, and Wizards.

Comment: @doubleDown Okay, then I'll just lock myself when you want to open me `:P` Also, unicorns are not safe? NONSENSE!

Comment: @gnat, by golly you are right. The SO/SE platform itself is a "new better solution to a problem"!

Comment: @Doorknob no, wouldn't want to argue with you.. but which is worse .. arguing with an inanimate object or a mythical being??? O.O Holy crap, that might be a good question for *drumroll* Stack Exchange!!!! hahahahahhahaha

Comment: @gnat I think you should totally post that as an answer because I don't want to have to end up accepting robertHarvey's answer since it only demeans my question

Comment: @aaronman there you go, [expanded it into an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189431/165773)

Comment: @Yve Hmm... Maybe... Let's ask on meta if we should ask on SE about questions on meta... My head asplode O_o

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [problem of low signal/noise ratio at forums](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/):

> Most forums and chat rooms have a scale problem. As in, *they don’t*. The more people that join the discussion, the more noise each of those connections bring. So the forums get progressively noisier and noisier, and suddenly one day … [you stop learning](http://scobleizer.com/2009/11/02/the-chat-roomforum-problem-an-apology-to-technosailor/).
>
> > … eventually the experts (i.e. people who are teaching you stuff) get drowned out and you are left with an experience that looks more like the magazine rack at a grocery store than a book shelf at Harvard. — Robert Scoble

Stack Overflow [solved this problem](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/#comment-60584):

> ...one of the things that drew us to Stack Overflow in the first place was the fact that its Q&A format offered an alternative to the morass of rants and platitudes consistently offered on other, less-modern discussion forums...

---

<sup>(*Carthago delenda est*) Per my observations, this solution [breaks at some hot questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164078/165773), but that's because of [bug in hotness formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164712/165773). Other than that, I find SNR fairly low compared to traditional discussion forums.</sup>

Comment: Even though your answer is obviously not what I expected, I appreciate your post because you definitely have a very valid point, hopefully some other people will try to find some more fitting answers since you answered I'm assuming you might be interested as well

Comment: +1 for fancy latin phrase in the footnote

Answer (score 7):

Is Stack Overflow a crucible/sandbox for new ideas or original research?

[I don't think so](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Finding novel solutions to oblique problems has never been SO's raison d'être, so why would we expect to find such solutions there?

Comment: as much as what your saying is true, your answer only attempts to shut down a question for which at least one person is curious to know the answer

Comment: I would say the aim of SO is to generate excellent answers, novel or otherwise

Comment: @RichardTingle: [It's not hard to find those](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert?tab=answers), and once in awhile you get a [real gem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/102937).

Comment: My point is that if novel answers aren't forbidden and you ask a hundred thousand questions some of the answers will inevitably be novel, most won't but some will. Especially with the likes of skeet about

Comment: Honestly I've seen the branch prediction question, it is very well explained, but I feel like anyone who had been thinking about BP at all could have answered it

Comment: @RichardTingle: The number of such questions must be vanishingly small; I've been here quite awhile, and I haven't seen one yet that could be characterized as original thought.  It shouldn't be all that surprising, really; Wikipedia has no original thought on it whatsoever.  In fact, their policy specifically prohibits original thought.