# What about capping the time a post remains in "Hot meta posts" instead of showing it for so long?

Tags: feature-request, community-bulletin

I have noticed that once a post in Meta gets some score, it gets boosted through the "Hot meta posts" section. That is great!

However, I also noticed (in a small Stack Exchange site) that it will stay there for weeks. From [How are the contents of the Community Bulletin determined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/209901) (kudos to Shadow Wizard for the link):

> - If there are still under 4 items, the rest of the space is filled with **[hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions** not marked
>     [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), scoring at least 3 and posted within the
>     past two weeks. These are picked semi-randomly. At least *one* of
>     these will always be added to the list, even if it pushes the length
>     over 4. (Note that the timing and tags [can be adjusted
>     per-site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268576/why-do-feature-requests-and-support-questions-appear-in-the-community-bulletin/268577#268577) to suit the needs of each community)

This happens even if the post does not get any feedback, nor up/down votes any more.

I don't think it is necessary having the same post in that prominent place for too long: most probably, almost everybody has seen it within the first days and keeping it up there does not give any extra value. On the contrary, it prevents people from reading that block of text because they can assume "it is always the same story".

What about setting a shorter limit of, say, 5 days or one week the most after last big action in the post like a new upvoted answer?

Comment: The answer is given in the dupe: "If there are still under 4 items, the rest of the space is filled with hot discussion questions not marked status-completed, scoring at least 3 and posted **within the past two weeks**". (the design has changed drastically since then, but as far as I can tell, the logic behind the hot meta posts is the same.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't say "hot questions", I said "hot meta posts". This is the title of the box.

Comment: I know, meant the tag you chose.

Comment: OK, agreed. Thanks for retagging.

Comment: That said, you can turn this question into a feature request asking only to reduce the time from two weeks to something lower, and I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that I was doing. Thanks for the support!

Comment: remotely related: [Don't let questions stick to the top of the hot questions list forever](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99077/165773)