# Should trending questions be auto-protected?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hot-questions, protected-questions, answer-quality

I noticed today that a request for protection came up due to the the large number of me-too answers on a trending question I answered recently.  This got me thinking, since trending questions get far more attention than the average question, should questions that trend be automatically protected?

On the upside, this does seem to be a common problem and the auto-protection could be put in place only while the question is trending.  On the downside, it would make it more difficult for new people to participate in answering a trending (highly visible) question so it could be a barrier to entry.

Thoughts?

Comment: This seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: "looking for long answers..." [notice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/post-notice/info "what's this"): 1) wouldn't make _a barrier to entry_ and 2) would give users and mods sufficient justification to delete metoo crap as a blatant violation of the "rules set for this game"

Comment: @gnat Seeing how many bounties you're putting up and the sheer indifference from the higher-ups, I think it's safe to say that we may need to take things into our own hands. 1) Get a gang of 3k users to close-vote everything stupid that tops the multicollider. 2) Offset the multicollider by manually redditing everything else that is good. (That is: Give even more attention to everything else that actually deserves it.) I don't like this latter method since it will lead to spamming. But it *has* proven effective in getting attention to those hidden jewels.

Comment: That said, I also don't like the idea of abusing close-votes and downvotes for the purpose of denying visibility... But there's no other alternative. In the recent months, I've been seeing people doing more and more of this. (That is: improperly close-voting a valid question to deny attention and thus leading to ridiculous close-reopen wars...)

Comment: @Mysticial [guerilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guerilla)! :) You're reading my mind; I was thinking about it, too - even prepared _legal justification_ for er "corrective voting". BTW regarding voting, per my observations even 3-4 coordinated DVs could make a substantial difference in hotness score; score sensitivity to manipulations like that is [explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164712/165773) - _"Yet another indication of issues with current formula..."_ Interesting to note that neither "my" nor "your" variant of formula wouldn't be as sensitive to such tricks but oh well

Comment: @gnat Haha... There really aren't too many options. So we're bound to come to the same ideas. :) Although I hesitate to recommend this, extending the coordinated downvotes to all the answers as well also helps to lower the hotness score. But anything beyond that is clear into the territory of "suspendable abuse". (Such as coordinated rollback wars (to get a post locked) and red-flagging.) (Not saying that improper and coordinated close-votes and downvotes aren't already "abusive".) But the fact that these nasty ideas even come to mind shows that there's a clear problem in the current system.

Comment: @gnat Agreed. And it's worse than that. They don't help as much and they cost -1 to cast. Furthermore, IIRC, only scores from the top 3 answers are counted towards `sum(Ascores)`. And the top 3 answers are usually the ones that are good. So now you're downvoting potentially good answers. On the flip-side, downvoting the tail of 0-score answers will let them be delete voted. But that needs to be done fast before the masses upvote them out of negative again.

Comment: anyway, my plan for next 3-5 weeks is rather peaceful: I am going to put 3-4 more related bounties (until my rep falls dangerously close to 2K) - after that, I'll likely be open to consider er more radical measures :)

Comment: Nah, don't waste all your rep on this. If we hear nothing anything after this one - assume it won't happen. (This comment trail should be a hint that things might get ugly if nothing is done.) I've already been testing the waters a bit in our C++ chatroom with coordinated deletion of late answers to popular questions. There's probably enough of us who are interested in targeting dumb things that top the multicollider. (since a number of us do regularly speak out against them... but only in chat)

Comment: hey! I recently saw a wonderful example of a terribly mediocre question with 20+ FGITW answers that had no chance at collider because of several DVs that strategically "balanced" about the same amount of upvotes. If memory serves, it was in C++ tag :)

Comment: @Mysticial on a further thought, I am inclined to stick with the _3-4 bounties_ plan. You see, it took me _more than a month_ between raising my feature request ([Jan 25](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5482/31260 "Trial run...")) and completion of underlying root cause analysis ([Mar 9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164712/165773 "rev 9, last substantial update to RCA post")). I believe it would be fair to give _higher-ups_ comparable amount of time to evaluate my findings

Comment: @gnat I just tested the "abuse CVs to deny visibility" idea on [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648312/what-does-an-underscore-mean-in-java) (I linked it in the C++ room.) Well... [it got ugly...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173714/can-we-nuke-this-too-localized-question)

Comment: @Mysticial that's wrong target for experimenting because question was recently highlighted at MSO. Meta views and votes substantially skew the results compared to "plain crowd attention" mode. By the way observing voting in "plain crowd" popular questions makes good food for thought. For example I recently seen 3 crappy answers in such a question DVed at early stage (by community regulars I guess) to `-1, -2, -3` and later counter-voted back to zero, where these were left hanging, without further upvotes. Interesting, isn't it?

Comment: @gnat It was the other way around: The meta post came *later*. When I saw the question, I knew right away that it would be the type that the C++ room would rage at. So I linked it there (to see if it would get it closed). In fact, they raged so much, that one of us made that meta post. *IOW, the meta post came as direct result of my decision to drop that question in the C++ room.*

Comment: @Mysticial ah! I see. That's an important thing to know, any kind publicity may have consequences you didn't predict - especially MSO publicity. :) Though I typically don't complain when things go like this. In "meta-highlighted" questions, one always has a chance to complain about particular crappy answer(s) and get them dealt with through voting or mod intervention. As you can see, that very question has "sane" amount of two answers so far (keeping fingers crossed)

Comment: @Mysticial btw, another thing worth experimenting with is [meta-tag:editing] the question. On one hand, it tends to decrease score due to effect of `Qupdated` part in the formula, on the other hand it [meta-tag:bump]s question, giving it a chance to gather more views and votes. In my experience, _accurate_ edits were mostly leading to more "fair" score: bump favors interesting questions which receive additional upvotes / views while bland ones tend to loose through `Qupdated`. As an example, for the question you mention my recent edit dropped its score from 100 to 84 in just few minutes...

Comment: @gnat It actually has no effect. The time decay is updated every top of the hour. You just happened to catch it at the top of the hour.

Comment: @Mysticial hm [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15648312/timeline) shows my edit at `05:00`, you're maybe right. Thanks! I'll take this into account in next experiments.

Comment: @Mysticial I think you might be interested in recent feature request: [In hotness formula, discard answers when voting evidence indicates that these are not good data points](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192046/165773) :)

Comment: @gnat I was the first to upvote it. :)

Comment: @Mysticial - would you be interested in [helping SE team test their experiments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218247/what-changed-in-the-hot-questions-sidebar-algorithm#comment710290_218248 "as explained here") in reordering hot questions? Inverted _guerilla_ if you wish... or maybe [italian strike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_strike)

Comment: @gnat It seems that I've already been put into the scrambling experiment... :)

Comment: @Mysticial I am in that group, too - and it turns out quite convenient, as I can learn whether the new algorithm is robust, by checking whether lemming-upvoted questions tend to stick at the top of the list shown to me or are being shuffled so that audience attention gets more balanced distribution. Pretty fascinating (though maybe part of the fun is because I am ex-tester and just enjoy trying to break things made by "them developers":)

Comment: @gnat I can't say I'm completely satisfied with it though. Genuinely good questions that *deserve* to be stuck at the top won't be able to stay at the top. IOW, it's "solving" the problem by equally nerfing all questions (good and bad) at the same time.

Comment: @Mysticial neither am I. Though, seeing questions with [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21559113/839601)-[3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553004/template-integer-parameter-constructor) answers entering the competition arena (at last!) makes me hope for better. Also, it feels like algorithm changes sometimes, ie what we observe now isn't necessarily the final version. That's why I try to stress-test it now, to make it easier for SE team to evaluate effects of whatever they're experimenting with

Comment: @Mysticial ...on a further thought, making a "sticky" exposure for SE audience might be fair, but not that healthy. _Lemmings pressure_ is really hard to handle, at least when it happens frequently (posts are rarely reddited, that hides the issues; at Programmers we have posts Ars'ed once a week - that's tough but manageable... but tough). From this perspective, sort of "interlacing" might indeed make sense: show it on top for like an hour, then hide for an hour to let community cleanup the lemmings garbage, then show again, hide again and so on

Comment: @gnat - I concur that this is addressed by that.

Comment: @AJHenderson I'd say that this is _superseded_ by that. Meaning, at first auto-protection was designed to kick in when there are 3 posts deleted, but this was further enhanced to handle broader range of cases, non necessarily involving deletion

Answer (score 20):

[As soon as three posts from low-rep users are deleted by mods or the community, the question is auto-protected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89971/151385). This threshold is pretty good in my opinion, it avoids shutting down external users from the start, while still protecting the true crap magnets.

Protecting is a far more dangerous tool than it appears at first glance, as it can prevent good content from ever being written in the first place. I think we should generally be careful when to use this tool.

Comment: That makes sense, perhaps it could be an optional feature for each site to decide the setting on depending on the normal level of activity on a particular site.  Some of the smaller sites can tend to be hit really hard really fast and have fewer moderators to deal with it.

Answer (score 8):

As Anna Lear [points out in another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164080/why-can-only-moderators-protect-questions-less-than-1-day-old/164083#164083), proactively protecting questions is generally a bad idea.

I generally keep an eye on Hacker News and other programmer sites for when our questions hit the front page. We as moderators try to keep an eye on these questions and actively moderate the bad stuff out quickly.

There is the possibility of 'going too far' and over moderating a post just because it's highly visible.  We want to keep that from happening, as that can color the outside world's opinion of Stack Overflow.

Comment: this reasoning is wrong. Anna ignores that [goal of hot questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions "see details here") is to simply "entertain" (according to Shog) / "explicitly expose interesting questions" (as Jeff put it). With goal like this, I can't see any sensible arguments why questions should remain unprotected. Striptease dancers aren't thrown in the crowd, they make their show secured

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HNqJur7RXY

Comment: @gnat "Wrong" *to you*.  I realize this [is a hot button issue for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions#comment713515_220099).

Comment: I merely commented about your approach [after I found out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions "here") that it looks simply logically incorrect

Comment: @gnat I won't hash this out in the comments with you (I recommend bringing up a meta question to talk about this specific logical flaw you mention), but my answer does not change: We're not worried about needing to auto-protect hot questions because we haven't seen a reason to have to need to do that yet.  Random google questions that the spammers go after are much more of a problem than the hot questions -- and there's no way to simply protect a question in advance because we won't know the spammers have hit it until there are already a few spam answers on it.

Comment: a more accurate analysis of the issue: [Auto-protect questions that get more than N answers from new users in a 24-hour period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226619). Supplementary reading for those interested to understand [specifics](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220325) of how hot questions are perceived by a typical SO regular: [“SO questions are penalized” in the hot list - how does that work, can it be done for other site(s)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226568) and [cultural clash](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/conversation/cultural-clash)