# Hot network questions should not include locked questions

Tags: bug, hot-questions

I was just now led to [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/101990), which appeared under "Hot Network Questions". However, it is locked since yesterday. Certainly, questions which are closed or locked should not be advertised as hot questions, so I believe this is a bug.

Comment: I disagree with your general assessment that this kind of behavior is a bug (feel free to try to change my mind) - but do you think this particular question should have been presented as hot, irrespective of its lock status? "too many comments" doesn't seem to be a pretty strong negative indicator of quality.

Comment: @JanDvorak My opinion on whether or not this particular question should have been presented as "hot" is not the point here, my point is that *locking* a question also makes it so that it doesn't appear any more in search results (of the SE search), so it appears counterproductive to the intention of locking (hence a bug) that it would continue to appear in the hot question list.

Answer (score 3):

No.

As far as I know and remember, closed questions are already excluded from the Hot Network Questions list, or more accurate a closed question can't become "Hot".

So, if a question is off topic for a site and should not get new answers, a moderator or five ordinary users can just close it.

Such locks as the one on the question you linked to are quite common and meant to prevent **comments**,  not answers. This should not affect the question visibility or its quality.

Comment: Note that the question mentioned by the OP is also *protected*. That might add to his/her experience that he/she can't do anything with it.

Comment: @Glorfindel that's a totally different thing, and protected questions shouldn't be excluded as well. On the contrary, there's a popular feature request asking [to auto protect all hot questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170419/should-trending-questions-be-auto-protected)

Comment: I know, I'm just pointing out a possible source of confusion.