# Does putting a question "{on Hold}" remove it from the SE network's Hot Questions list?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, on-hold

Yesterday the Super User question [What does XP in Windows XP stand for?](https://superuser.com/questions/1187666/what-does-xp-in-windows-xp-stand-for) was on the [SE network Hot Question's list](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot). That question is now on Hold. I also notice it's no longer on the Hot Question list.

**Does putting a question on Hold remove it from the Hot Question's list?**

I reviewed the Meta question *[What formula should be used to determine “hot” questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/271445)* but did not find my answer there.

*I've never personally seen a hot question that was also on hold, but I'm asking this question in hopes of an answer based on more authority than my own fallible opinion.*

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does, but I also can't find anywhere this is documented.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287732, has an answer, but not conclusive. Still looking for an official comment on it.

Comment: There is also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212835 but I did not read it closely enough to know if it answers the question. It does seem vague, though.

Comment: @JasonC The second [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139102/271445) you linked doesn't appear to answer the question.

Comment: @Twisty Well, the HNQ used to be [in the drop-down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM5aB.png) instead of in the side bar, so it's about the same list. But yeah I dunno.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, on hold/closed questions are excluded from the Hot Network Questions list as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/152859):

> - Closed questions are excluded

Note that the HNQ list is heavily cached (it might be up to one hour as far as I remember), so if a question enters the list and only then is put on hold, it won't be removed right away.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether questions placed On Hold are removed from the Hot Network Questions list, and from comments on this question whether that happens seems uncertain, but I think that they should be removed.

Since anything on the Hot Network Questions list is likely to be seen by many users of many sites I think we want these questions to be great examples of what can be achieved using the Stack Exchange protocols for focussed Q&A.